# How do websites use the first part of the url as a variable, like twitter.com/Name

Tags: php

I know how to use variable in a url like `example.com/page.php/variable` using `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` but I want to know how a similar thing can be done using the first part of the url, like twitter does: `twitter.com/name` using php and apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of using .htaccess. Know more about it [here](http://www.htaccess-guide.com).

We actually specify in .htaccess about how url structure comes.  Below is the simple one.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /?name=$1 [L]
```

The above code will actually do like this. you pass a url as `www.example.com/page.html` and it actually gets converted as `www.example.com/?name=page`. If you remove `.html` this actually will have `www.example.com/page`. Hope this helps you and you can find a lot of tutorials on it if you search on google.

Comment: This doesn't work. I added this code to my .htaccess and tried to go to example.com/test.html but I get a 404 error. I'd like to make it so that anything entered after example.com/ becomes a GET variable.

Comment: For my uses, I need to be able to go to example.com/testname and have that do the same thing as going to example.com/index.php?name=testname

Comment: Please read  this [link](http://example.comhttp://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) once. Get a good grasp on htaccess first so that it becomes very handy to you.

Comment: I actually found that I needed to allowoverride all in httpd.conf to get my htaccess to work and got the "Basic URL Rewriting" example from that page to work. I'm now having trouble changing "pet-care" to mean all pages. I tried this:
`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?name=$1 [L]`
But I can't get a grasp of how to use those characters to define the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the parse_url() function in PHP.
This function creates an array filled with information about the URL you gave

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

From: php.net:

```
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're using apache, you can edit [htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) files to meet your needs.
there's plenty feature of htaccess, for changing url behaviour you can use [mod_rewrite](http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/) feature